# Is it necessary to close a Netty ChunkedInput?

Tags: java, netty, nio, channel

As stated in the question, is it necessary to close a Netty `ChunkedInput` after sending its data through `ChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush()`? I know this operation is asynchronous so probably I am not supposed to close it immediately after calling `writeAndFlush()`, therefore do I need to add a `FutureListener` to close it?

In the official [*File server*](https://netty.io/4.1/xref/io/netty/example/http/file/package-summary.html) example, I fuond that the the `close()` function of the `ChunkedInput` is not called:

```
sendFileFuture = ctx.writeAndFlush(new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, fileLength, 8192)), ctx.newProgressivePromise());
```

Does it mean that the `ChunkedInput` is closed automatically when all the data is read, or does the channel actually help me close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you almost never need to close the `ChunkedInput` yourself, since you will normally have a `ChunkedWriteHandler` in the pipeline which will close it for you after the last chunk is written. See [code](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/f6251c8256d8ce3fb6fb76df23e477caa15f627b/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/stream/ChunkedWriteHandler.java#L322).

> Does it mean that the ChunkedInput is closed automatically when all the data is read

There was a bug long back that closed the input after the data was read, but it has been fixed to close the input after the last chunk is written. See https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/fb52b8a3b2e3940a0bcf6e9167b157d59a811691

In the example you reference, the pipeline includes a `ChunkedWriteHandler` and the `ChunkedFile` (implementation of `ChunkedFile`) is closed automatically.